# yahoo AutoComplete widget Dropdown is floating when scrolling the page

Tags: autocomplete, scroll, widget, yahoo, freeze

I have yahoo autocomplete widget on my web page. if you click on Button a dropdown appears. Now if the page on which dropdown appears have scroll bars and you try to scroll, the whole page gets scrolled But the Dropdown retain the same place.

I have instantiated the auto complete widget as following:

```
new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete("inputBox.id", "inputBox.container_id", dataSource);
```

So how we can make the dropdown move with the text field while scrolling?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Problem, the position style of yui-ac-container was override in my case. Because of that the dropdown was floating in the air. Changed the postition attribute from fixed to absolute and it work as expected.